# SMART data dialog appears on each return from TTY to GUI

Tags: 16.04, smart

Each time I return from TTY back to GUI environment , I am greeted with this dialog

[image]

This has started after upgrade to 16.04 LTS from 14.04 LTS. How do I prevent this dialog from popping up ?

Comment: Could you add what in details to the question or make another screenshot?

Comment: @user.dz found the solution - it was due to psensor. When you asked for details, i recalled it's possible to check `auth.log`. Thank you ! Your comment essentially helped me find the solution, although not directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having remembered that all authentication requests go into `/var/log/auth.log`, I've reproduced the dialog by switching to TTY1 and returned to GUI. After the dialog appeared and I canceled the password prompt, i found the following entry:

> Oct  3 12:33:43 eagle polkitd(authority=local): Operator of
>   unix-session:c2 FAILED to authenticate to gain authorization for
>   action org.freedesktop.udisks2.ata-smart-update for
>   system-bus-name::1.83 **[psensor]** (owned by unix-user:xieerqi)

`psensor` is an appindicator for monitoring temperature ( and memory and CPU usage ). Having checked it's settings, it became apparent that it has option for updating `Udisks` information. Unchecking and rebooting ( although restarting `psensor` itself would have been sufficient ) has solved the issue - I don't get the annoying SMART data prompts anymore

[image]